# Dynamically loading two libpython versions

Tags: python, c, dynamic

I have a program which embeds both python2 and python3 interpreters.  The libpython shared libraries are `dlopen()`ed by the respective commands which provide access to the interpreters and each interpreter maintains its own state.

This all works just fine if the user only uses pure python modules or builtins.  Trying to load a C extension (like termios) then complains "undefined symbol: PyExc_TypeError".  This happens because the C extensions aren't linked against libpython.  Python upstream doesn't think this is a [problem](http://bugs.python.org/issue4434).

To get around that, I can change the `dlopen()` calls in my program for the libpython shared libraries to use `RTLD_GLOBAL`.  As soon as I do that, however, trying to use both the python2 and python3 interpreters in the same session of the program causes it to ABRT in the process of calling `Py_Initialize` for whichever interpreter was invoked second.  Using only one of the interpreters works fine.

Any idea how to get this to work when the C extensions won't be linked against libpython, therefore requiring the use of `RTLD_GLOBAL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this won't work the way you want it to. The solution ordinarily would involve linking each extension to versioned libpython symbols; or one could have a namespace-capable linker, such that one could map each library to a different namespace, rather than a global one. Unfortunately neither of these options are easily applied, so you're probably stuck with a multi-process model. Simply fork and have one process link to each version of Python. The tough bit then is how to share whatever data led you to require two distinct Python interpreters in the first place. Perhaps a description of what problem led to the question may help find a better solution?

Comment: The program allows using the python interpreter for scripting.  It previously only supported Python2 but recently gained Python3 support.  The idea was not to force one option or the other, especially since there exists scripts already written using the Python2 interface.  I guess it could be changed to keep track of whether one interface has already been loaded and then prevent the other one from loading.  This still gives the flexibility to build with both interpreters but avoids the whole crashing problem. :)

Comment: That would seem the easy workaround, albeit somewhat limited. The more complex option is separating your scripting interface from the language bindings, running that interface through subprocesses, and then let each subprocess link to whichever version you like. It won't be quite as efficient, and might be entirely impractical depending on your current interface, but may be doable considering that you can dlopen it now.